# Sage 50 Accounts Database Schema

Tags: database, odbc, schema, sage-line-50

I am accessing Sage 50 data via their ODBC Driver but cannot seem to establish if the tables have a unique / primary key. The ODBC.NET Driver does not seem to return any information relating to indexes or key field information.

Anyone got any clues?

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables ending in "m" seem to be master tables with actual real data in...

Don't know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 3):

On the main objects such as Customers, Suppliers the Key indexed fields are `ACCOUNT_REF`, if its a transaction file you would join on `HEADER.HEADER_NUMBER` -> `SPLIT.HEADER_NUMBER` - they work on old school linked lists are are not indexed

For Sales or Purchase Orders, Invoice documents you would join `INVOICE.INVOICE_NUMBER` to `INVOICE_ITEM.INVOICE_NUMBER`

Answer (score 0):

I created a ODBC data source and exported the data in excel and it clearly shows the table names, columns and data.

Comment: but the question - albeit vague - was about the schema, i.e. indexes/types/lengths/etc of those columns

Answer (score 0):

Check the sage 50 [data dictionary](http://www.sage.com/na/~/media/site/sage-50-accounting-ca/PDF/intelligence/DataDict_2013.pdf) lots of information about the database such as: columns , indexes, keys, length, type , descriptions.

Comment: Bear in mind, this dictionary for US/CA version and it does not apply to UK version of Sage 50 Accounts to the best of my knowledge

Answer (score -1):

Sage Line 50 uses a proprietry database.  As far as I am aware there is no indexing of the tables.